Null sets of pushforward measure
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a random variable and $P^X$ the pushforward measure on the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $g=h$ $P^X$-almost surely. Can I deduce that $g\circ X=h\circ X$ $P$-almost surely?
I know that for any null set $N$ under $P^X$ in the Borel sigma algebra, $X^{-1}(N)$ must be a null set under $P$ in $\mathcal{F}$. But aren't there more null sets to consider to let the statement hold?
EDIT: The reasoning might go like this(?): Since $g$ and $h$ can only differ on $\{N\in\mathfrak{B}:P^X(N)=0\}$, the only elements in $\Omega$ on which $g\circ X$ and $h\circ X$ can differ must be mapped by $X$ into any of the sets in $\{N\in\mathfrak{B}:P^X(N)=0\}$. These are the sets $\{X^{-1}(N)\in\mathfrak{B}:P^X(N)=0\}$, which are nullsets with respect to $P$. Therefore $g\circ X=h\circ X$ $P$-almost surely?
How can I write this more nicely?

$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega : g(X(\omega)) \ne h(X(\omega))\}) = P^X(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : g(x) \ne h(x)\}) = 0.$$
The first equality is by the definition of $P^X$. The second equality is by the assumption that $g=h$ holds $P^X$-almost surely.

Thank you! I could also just write $P({g\circ X = h\circ X})=P^X({g=h})=1$, right?
